# Start Point for Child Process in Windows C programming

Tags: c, windows, server

To create Multi-Process environment; we need to start a New Process as a child process of current process. Is it possible to define start point for newly created child process ? Like Threading. We want to have separate data section / Memory hence Do Not want to go for Multi Threading. This needs to be develop in windows C environment.

Comment: I think the new proccess needs to be an own .exe

Comment: No, you cannot specify a different start point for a child process.  However, your child process can read an argument from the command line (or the environment block, or via IPC, but the command line is usually easiest) that tells it where to start.